# Jackson serialize the child class as fields in parent class

Tags: json, serialization, jackson

I am trying to obtain the following effect.

```
class Foo{
    public Bar bar;
    public int f1 = 1;
}

public class Bar{
    public int b1;
    public int b2;
}
```

If you serialize this to JSON you will get

```
{ "bar" : {
              "b1" : 1,
              "b2" : 2,
          },
   "f1" : 0
}
```

But I am loking on the Jackson annotations to have it written as

```
{  
   "b1" : 1,
   "b2" : 2,        
   "f1" : 0
}
```

Basically you do not serialize the field as a separate class, but rather pull the fields to its parent object in the tree.

I know that this could be done with a custom serializer, but I am curios if there is a simple annotation style for this. (For a single field I could have annotated with `@JsonValue`)

Comment: I’m curious why you want to do this instead of using the nested serialization that is default?

Comment: The json is read like this by another service, but the class hierarchy is like this on the writer end

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `@JsonUnwrapped`

```
class Foo{
    @JsonUnwrapped
    public Bar bar;
    public int f1 = 1;
}
```

If you can't edit your class, then use [Mixin](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonMixInAnnotations) or custom serializer.

Use `@JsonCreator` if you need [deserialization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16570333/1032167)

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was searching for