# @JSONUnwrapped on the embedded field flattened issue

Tags: java, jackson

I have class:

```
public class Person{
private int id;
@JsonUnwrapped
private Father father
//getters/setters

@ToString
@Accessors
public static class Father{
  private String name;
  private String surname;
}
```

and form following JSON file

```
{
  "id": 12,
  "name": "Ned",
  "surname": "Stark"
}
```

while reading:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Person myPerson =
        mapper.readValue(new File("src/main/resources/data/rest/person.json"), Person.class);
 System.out.println(myPerson);
```

I keep getting:

```
(...) father=Student.Father(name=null, surname=null)
```

with error:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No
>   serializer found for class
>   com.example.demo.rest.r01_json.Person$Father and no properties
>   discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable
>   SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain:
>   com.example.demo.rest.r01_json.Person["father"]

**What shall I correct to provide the flattened father content? Or it is not possible and  I must put it as an nested JSON object like**?:

```
"father":{
  "name": "Ned",
  "surname": "Stark"
}
```

EDIT

I have edited it to add `Person` cosntructor with

```
 @JsonCreator // DESERIALIZATION: JSON -> POJO
  public Person(
...

      @JsonProperty("name") String name,
      @JsonProperty("surname") String surname) {
...
    this.father = new Father(name, surname);
```

with `Father` nested within `Person` class:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
  private static class Father {
    private String name;
    private String surname;
  }
```

still getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `com.example.demo.rest.r01_json.Person$Father` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the Jackson deserialization equivalent of @JsonUnwrapped?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16570073/whats-the-jackson-deserialization-equivalent-of-jsonunwrapped)

Comment: @MichałZiober I have edited the question. Can you please reffer to thte edit? What is still the problem?

Comment: Which version of `Jackson` do you use? Why `Father` class is declared as `private static class`? It is not visible for other classes. Why you have created new question: [@JsonUnwrapped and @JsonCreate for same field causes issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55130687/jsonunwrapped-and-jsoncreate-for-same-field-causes-issues)?